# Django, project model and admin created, views.py not responding

Tags: python, django

Ok, so maybe since I am sick today I'm doing something VERY silly, but it drives me completely crazy.

I am writing a django plugin and it view / url aren't responding. 
I mean, if I edit the admin plugin I will have error, if I edit wrongly the model, the server will crash etc.

But whatever I do to my views / urls, nothing happen.

So here is my main urls.py :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.conf.urls import *  # NOQA
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from . import views

from djangocms_blog.sitemaps import BlogSitemap
from djangocms_extend.cms_sitemap import CMSAlternateHreflangSitemap


admin.site.site_header = _('MyApplication')
admin.site.site_title = _('MyApplication administration')
admin.site.index_title = _('MyApplication administration')

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
  url(r'^share/', views.shareblipp),
  url(r'^api-job_plugin/', include('djangocms_job.urls')),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
  url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

and my applicaiton urls.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

from .views import ArticleListView

urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  url(r'^$', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='articles-list'),
)
```

It's working perfectly with other applications in the same directory lvl as this one.

I know it might be hard to answer my problem, to be honest I am more looking for new clue to explore.

Thanks in advance for the time spend on it

EDIT :
when you are producing an application linking djangocms and django admin, a cms_app.py with the line :
urls = ['myapplication.urls']

is needed and will be hook with :

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
```

.

Damn #hard-silly-time.

Comment: What is your application? Is it `cms`?

Comment: Well, I have a cms part and a django admin one.
At the moment I have to list the article setup in the model / admin.

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to understand which bit in the main urls.py is including your "application" urls.

Comment: My bad, I found the answer